# Run two Python programs every 30 minutes

Tags: pi-3, cron, python-2.x

I have two Python 2.7 programs. When I boot the Raspberry Pi I want to run that programs automatically. I also want to very 30 minutes close that programs and run them again. I imagine that the best option for that is Cron, but if I run again the Python programs are going to close the previous ones? Can anyone help me to program this project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use crontab as mentioned by Conor. You can run as many scripts as you want and they won't affect each other. I have these setup on all my Pis to run bash and python scripts. It looks a bit intimidating at first as crontab generates a template but you can erase all of it and use the configuration below.

```
$ crontab -e

## Crontab Configuration ##
29,59 * * * * (bash -c 'pkill -f scriptName.py') #This will kill your task on the 29th and 59th minute of every hour.
0,30 * * * * (bash -c 'cd ~/path/to/script && python scriptName.py') #This will run your task on the 0th and 30th minute of every hour.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use cron to run a script that first closes any existing instance of the program, and then starts a new one. "killall" works well to kill any existing instances, usually

Comment: Yes, I will try it, but killall was just what I was looking for. Thanks.